# Need some grub help

Tags: grub2

I used to run Win10 on an SSD, wanted to try Ubuntu so I bought a second SSD.

> Removed the old Win10 SSD
>
> installed the new SSD with Ubuntu 22.04

I've been running Ubuntu for about a month and love it, except I still need my game machine (Win10).

so, I decided to set up grub for a dual boot system.

> I reconnected the Win10 SSD drive
>
> Ran update-grub

Now, when I reboot I get the grub menu, but there's no Windows option.

let me know if/what info you need.

Update: I used the Boot-Repair-Disk and got Windows to show up in grub menu, when I select Win10 it complains that 'this is not a valid boot disk'...

Comment: Try to fix that old SSD because some boot files may got damaged. I don't remember any process now. BUT you can reboot with the Windows Installation Bootable and using the prompt command do a lot of things, I'm not sure if `sfc /now` will help. But you also have an option to fix boot through there something like `fixmbr`. And `bcdedit.exe {bootnamehere} options` to change others.

Comment: Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI? Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives? Do you have good backups of both systems?